# How to disallow focus at a readOnly field

Tags: forms, extjs, field, readonly

We have a form with few fields marked as readOnly.

The issue is that the user is able to focus or navigate to these readOnly fields using mouse or keyboard tab, and we want to disallow this.

One way of not allowing this is to mark all such fields as 'disabled'. But when marked disabled, then though fields can not be focussed, but then these disabled fields also do not get submitted to the server which is not what is expected.

Thus, how can we prevent a focus at readOnly fields?

PS: The reason behind disallowing focus at readOnly fields is to provide better navigation through keyboards, so that by using tab key user navigates or jumps across only those fields which he can edit and all readOnly fields get ignored.

Comment: would setting the tabIndex of the fields you want to focus on help

Comment: @gunnx: Thanks Gunnx, actually setting tabindex makes things specific and contextual, we unfortunately have about 300 forms and were trying to have a more general solutions to this issue. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please stop putting tags in your title. There is no need to prefix your title with `ExtJS:` or `ExtJs 4.1:` - That is what tags are for.

Comment: @meagar: Adding the technology in the title/body helps in increasing the readability of the stuff. I went through this post - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-bracketed-tags-from-question-titles - but then too, I feel that if I add the technology in the title/body then it gets more readable.

Comment: @netamp That's what tags are for. Duplicating the tags in the title means you have less usable title space.

Comment: @meagar: Pretty valid point. Will surely try to avoid doing so in future.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a listeners to the base Field class that listens for focus events then if the field is readOnly to focus the next component.

```
listeners: {
    focus: function(field)
    {                       
        if (field.readOnly)
        {
            field.nextSibling().focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: true, we are attempting this only, but this unfortunately stops working if the next sibling does not exist, that is, if the field is currently the last one in the screen and there are buttons present next to it. In such a case, the focus removes at that field only and does not move away from it. We also tried with nextNode() but that also gives same result. Any other idea? Thanks for the time so far.

Comment: You could assign the result of field.nextSibling() and test if null or not.
var nextField = field.nextSibling();

Comment: yeah.. we have used it and with this test we were able to make it out that whether the next field exists or not and called the function to focus it accordingly, but the main issue is that if we have a disabled field without any sibling, then focus would go to say buttons existing after that field, but here, in this case, the focus stays on the same field instead of going to the buttons.

Comment: Are those buttons inside the same container? If not then I dont think nextSibling will work as you except. If they are not in the same container is it possible to move them into it?

Comment: Agreed.. but the problem is that the number of forms are about 300 and all having different style as per the specific needs. Thus, a generic solution is being sought after in which readOnly behaves the same way as disabled in case of focus management.

Comment: Trying the other way then disabling the fields with disabled: true and then overriding the form submit to include disabled fields.

See code in last post here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?35949-SOLVED-how-do-you-override-Ext.lib.Ajax/page2

You will see how they ignore the disabled flag

Comment: Looks like to be the only decent solution. Thanks @gunnx for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Just override getSubmitData method and assign some other property to let overridden method know you want to submit regardless (say, forceSubmit):

```
Ext.define('My.form.Field', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Field',

    getSubmitData: function() {
        var me   = this,
            data = null;

        if ( me.disabled && me.readOnly && me.forceSubmit ) {
            data = {};
            data[me.getName()] = '' + me.getValue();
        }
        else {
            return me.callParent();
        }

        return data;
    }
});
```

Then you can require this class in your code and set the fields you need to be disabled, readOnly and have forceSubmit:

```
my field = new Ext.form.field.Text({
    disabled:    true,
    readOnly:    true,
    forceSubmit: true,

    value: 'foo'
});
```

That should do the trick.